# Thunderbird and desktop calendar

Tags: evolution, thunderbird, google-calendar, calendar

Is there a way I can use Thunderbird to access and modify my desktop calendar (Or anything other than evolution for that matter)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. The closest thing I can think of is an add-on to Thunderbird that mirrors the Lightning calendar to Evolution; you can get it from here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/9656/
However, it's a one way sync (TB->Evolution).